# How do I get a nether portal working in multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friend is running a server on Beta 1.8 and we can't get to the nether. I'm confused, since everywhere I've read says you've been able to do that since Beta 1.6. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a properly lit nether gate? What happens when you try to go through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that a vanilla server? Look into the file `server.properties` then set to true the properties `allow-nether=true`.

Is it a Bukkit server? Look into Permissions, maybe they are wrongly set up.

You can also try [MultiVerse-NetherPortals](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/multiverse-netherportals/) if server is Bukkit.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if it's your server, then open server.properties and make sure that it says "true" after the word allow-nether. If it is not yours,  then the creator probably has it "false", which disables the nether.